# How to display uploaded photos in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am building a user profile in codeigniter. I have set up a system that allows the user to create a folder with their user-id, and then upload photos to it. I have been abel to successfully upload files to a folder but I am just not sure how to display the photo in my view pertinent to the user.

I would assume I attach it to my `$user['']` just not sure exactly how to do that. Thanks in advance.

```
public function upload()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $user = $this->account_model->user();
        $data['user'] = $user;
        echo $user['id'];
        $user_folder = './uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('id');
        if(!is_dir($user_folder)){

            mkdir($user_folder, 0777);
        }
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $user_folder;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 50;
        $config['height']   = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $config['upload_path'] = $user_folder;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        //$config['max_size']   = '165';
        $config['max_width']  = '165';
        $config['max_height']  = '165';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {

            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['main_content'] = '/account/upload';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $data['main_content'] = '/account/success';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
    }
    public function img(array $user=array()) {
        if(!isset($user['relation'])) {
            return '';
        }
        $path = '';
        if($user['relation'] != 'Choose One') {
            $path = '/styles/images/Sharpie' . $user['relation'] . '.gif';
        }
        return $path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public function view_image($user_id)
{
     $this->load->model('account_model');

     $data['image'] = $this->account_model('model_that_will_fetch_relevant_image');

     $this->load->view('where_image_is',$data);

}
```

model:

```
public function get_image($user_id)
{ 

 $this->db->select('stuff'): \\ Select image filename

 $this ->db->where('table_that_has_user_id', $user_id ); 

 $query =  $this->db->get($this->_table_name . ' as aliase'); \\ where filename is

 return $query->result();
 }
```

view:

```
<img src = "<?=site_url('path/on/server/' . $image['image_filename']); ?>">
```

This assumes you are storing the image filename in a mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Users_model extends CI_Model {

   var $table = 'tbl_admin';

   function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->database();
   }

   public function processLogin($username,$password){ 
       $this->db->select('username,password');
       $where = $array = array('username' =>$username,'password'=>$password);
       $this->db->where($where);
       $this->db->from($this->table);
       $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, I hope it will help you.

Using **profile_image** variable you can display image.

```
<?php 

public function upload()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $user = $this->account_model->user();
        $data['user'] = $user;
        echo $user['id'];
        $user_folder = './uploads/' . $this->session->userdata('id');
        if(!is_dir($user_folder)){

            mkdir($user_folder, 0777);
        }
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $user_folder;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 50;
        $config['height']   = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $config['upload_path'] = $user_folder;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        //$config['max_size']   = '165';
        $config['max_width']  = '165';
        $config['max_height']  = '165';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {

            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $data['main_content'] = '/account/upload';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $image = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $data['profile_image'] = $user_folder.$image['upload_data']['file_name'];
            $data['main_content']  = '/account/success';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
    }
    public function img(array $user=array()) {
        if(!isset($user['relation'])) {
            return '';
        }
        $path = '';
        if($user['relation'] != 'Choose One') {
            $path = '/styles/images/Sharpie' . $user['relation'] . '.gif';
        }
        return $path;
    }
}
```